# Renaming multiple files using Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, move

I have a lot of files in this format:

```
D:\images\AAA_BBB\image\whatever1.jpg  
D:\images\AAA_BBB\image\whatever2.jpg
D:\images\FFF_EEE_CCC\image\asdf1.jpg
D:\images\FFF_EEE_CCC\image\asdf2.jpg
D:\images\WWW_XXX_YYY_ZZZ\image\someimage1.jpg
D:\images\WWW_XXX_YYY_ZZZ\image\someimage2.jpg
```

I'd like to move and rename these files using a substring of the absolute file path and remove the original files so that the results will look something like the below, starting with `0`.

```
D:\images\AAA\AAA_0.jpg
D:\images\AAA\AAA_1.jpg
D:\images\EEE\EEE_0.jpg
D:\images\EEE\EEE_1.jpg
D:\images\YYY\YYY_0.jpg  
D:\images\YYY\YYY_1.jpg
```

*Note that the number of tokens in the folder with the underscores can be any length*.

The following attempt, would only give me the 2nd token starting from the front. Using "Tokens=-2" to get the 2nd last token wouldn't output anything.

```bash
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

PushD "D:\images" || Exit /B

For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /A:D /B 2^>NUL
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R  "^[^_][^_]*_[^_][^_]*_[^_][^_]*_"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=2 EOL=? Delims=_" %%H In ("%%G") Do (
    Set "i=-1"
    For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%I In ('Dir "%%G\image" /A:-D /B') Do (
        Set /A i += 1
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Ren "%%G\image\%%I" "%%H_!i!%%~xI" && (
            If Not Exist "%%H\." MD "%%H"
            Move /Y "%%G\image\%%H_!i!%%~xI" "%%H"
        )
        EndLocal
    )
)

PopD
```

Then I used different logic by trying two `for` loops to get the last token, and then the 2nd last token, but it didn't work.

```bash
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

PushD "D:\images" || Exit /B

For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /A:D /B 2^>NUL
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R  "^[^_][^_]*_[^_][^_]*_[^_][^_]*_"'
) Do (
    Set "dirName=%%G"
    Set "lastSegment="
    For %%H In ("!dirName:_=" "!") Do (
        Set "secondLastSegment=!lastSegment!"
        Set "lastSegment=%%~H"
    )
    Set "segment=%%~xG"
    Set "i=-1"
    For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%I In ('Dir "%%G\image" /A:-D /B') Do (
        Set /A i += 1
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Ren "%%G\image\%%I" "!secondLastSegment!_!i!!segment!" && (
            If Not Exist "!secondLastSegment!\." MD "!secondLastSegment!"
            Move /Y "%%G\image\!secondLastSegment!_!i!!segment!" "!secondLastSegment!"
        )
        EndLocal
    )
)

PopD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

pushd "D:\images" || exit /B

for /D %%d in (*_*) do (
   set "oldName=%%d"
   for %%b in (".!oldName:_=.!") do for %%c in ("%%~Nb") do set "newName=%%~Xc"
   set "newName=!newName:~1!"
   md "!newName!"
   set "i=-1"
   for %%f in ("%%d\image\*.jpg") do (
      set /A i+=1
      move "%%~f" "!newName!\!newName!_!i!%%~Xf"
   )
)
```

Your examples have a lot of unneeded or redundant code...

- In general, it is not necessary to use a `for /F` command when you just want to process files or folders; plain `for` or `for /D` are simpler and works faster than `for /F`.
- A `for /D %%d in (*_*) do` command process all folders with at least one underscore; I don't see why you use a `findstr` with a complicated regex...
- See my trick to extract *the second last name* using `~Name` and `~eXtension` FOR command parameter modifiers.
- If you process each source folder once you just need to create the corresponding target folder *once*. You don't need to check if such a folder exist *in each file*. If the target folder may previously exist, you can check it just once per source folder...

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your provided information, does this help you out?

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "BaseDir=D:\images"

PushD "%BaseDir%" 2>NUL || Exit /B
For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "*_*" /A:D-L /B /O:N 2^>NUL
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "[^_][^_]*_[^_][^_]*"') Do (
    PushD "%%G"
    For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%H In ('Dir "image\*.jpg" /A:-D-L /B 2^>NUL
     ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /INR "\.jpg$"') Do (
        For /F "Delims=_" %%J In ("%%G") Do (
            If Not Exist "%BaseDir%\%%J\." MD "%BaseDir%\%%J"
            Move /Y "%BaseDir%\%%G\image\%%~I" "%BaseDir%\%%J\%%J_%%H%%~xI"
        ) 1>NUL
    )
    PopD
)
PopD
```

*Please be aware that you may have empty directories which you may wish to clean up too!*

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "sourcedir=u:\images"

FOR /f %%e IN ('DIR /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*_*"') DO (
 rem %%e has firstlevel subdirectory name - must have at least one "_"
 SET "L2=%%e"
 FOR %%o IN (!L2:_^= !) DO SET "destsub=!prevpart!"&SET "prevpart=%%o"
 FOR /f %%y IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%%e\image\*.jpg"') DO (
  MD "%sourcedir%\!destsub!" >nul 2>NUL
  SET "needtomove=Y"
  FOR /L %%u IN (0,1 9999) DO IF DEFINED needtomove IF NOT EXIST "%sourcedir%\!destsub!\!destsub!_%%u.jpg" move "%sourcedir%\%%e\image\%%y" "%sourcedir%\!destsub!\!destsub!_%%u.jpg" >nul&SET "Needtomove="
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Find each subdirectory that contains `_`. Find the second-last `_`-separated element by replacing `_`s with spaces and using a `for`. For each `*.jpg` in the ssubdirectory\image, try to make its destination (2>nul suppresses error messages like "Directory already exists") then try to find the first available namein the destination directory (since there is no guarantee that stray files don't already exist in the destination) and make the move.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code, which I want to eliminate:

- Your `findstr` filter is too strict, hence it would only let the last two images in your example list be processed. Let me recommend to completely remove it and use the directory mask `*_*` instead.
- The target directory does not need to be attempted to become created per each image file; one attempt per source directory is sufficient.
- Checking a directory for existence by `if exist` results in a wrong result when appending `\.` to the path (when it points to a file rather than a directory, it is also reported as existing); instead `\*` should be appended, so files are reported as not existing.
- You should specify a file name mask like `*.jpg` and/or `*.png` for the image files to be processed in order to filter out unintended ones.
- Perhaps you should specify a sort order for the image files to be processed, because otherwise, the file system determines the order, which may not be what you expect.
- Variable `segment` will be empty, because `%%~xG` is going to be blank (based on your examples). You most probably meant `%%~xI`.
- Although technically working, first renaming the current image file and then moving it into another sub-directory is not necessary; a single movement operation is enough.
- After movement of image files, empty sub-directories may remain, which should become cleaned up.
- When using `setlocal` for environment localisation, usage of `pushd` is mostly not necessary, because `setlocal` comprises the current working directory also. Remember that lack of `popd` may leave unwanted `pushd` stack entries behind, in contrast to `setlocal`, because `endlocal` always becomes implicitly executed when a batch script is terminated.
- [Delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) should not be globally enabled, because file/directory names containing `!` or `^` in their names might cause issues.

Here is your code with said issues fixed (without touching the intrinsic methodology):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Usage of `pushd`/`popd` is usually not needed when using `setlocal`/`endlocal`:
cd /D "%~dp0images" || exit /B

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%G in ('
    rem/ // The `findstr` filter was too strong and is unnecessary ^(a simple `dir` is enough^)^^! ^& ^
        2^> nul dir /B /A:D-H-S-L "*_*"
') do (
    set "dirName=%%G"
    set "lastSegment="
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to have it enabled only when necessary to not lose `!`-symbols:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%H in ("!dirName:_=" "!") do for %%J in ("!lastSegment!") do (
        endlocal
        set "secondLastSegment=%%~J"
        set "lastSegment=%%~H"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    rem /* Creation of the target directory is now done once per source directory
    rem    (to check whether a directory exists, append `\*` rather than `\.`): */
    if not exist "!secondLastSegment!\*" md "!secondLastSegment!"
    endlocal
    set "targetDir=%%G\image"
    rem // Since `%%~xG` is going to be blank, `segment` will be empty and is therefore useless:
    rem/ set "segment=%%~xG"
    set /A "i=-1"
    rem /* The `dir` should specify the file name mask(s) to exclude non-image files
    rem    (a sort order is now specified; hidden, system and linked items are now excluded): */
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('cd /D "%%G\image" ^&^& dir /B /A:-D-H-S-L /O:DN "*.jpg" "*.png"') do (
        set /A "i+=1"
        set "fileName=%%I"
        rem // Variable `segment` is empty; use `%%~xI` instead:
        set "fileExt=%%~xI"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "newFileName=!secondLastSegment!_!i!!fileExt!"
        rem/ ren "!targetDir!\!fileName!" "!newFileName!" && (
            rem The target directory has already been created at this point.
            rem/ move /Y "!targetDir!\!newFileName!" "!secondLastSegment!"
        rem/ )
        
        
        rem /* Instead of renaming and then moving, a single move operation suffices
        rem    (note that variable `segment` is empty, hence use `%%~xI` instead): */
        > nul move /Y "!targetDir!\!fileName!" "!secondLastSegment!\!newFileName!"
        rem // Clean up potentially empty sub-directory:
        2> nul rd "!targetDir!"
        endlocal
    )
    rem // Clean up potentially empty source directory:
    2> nul rd "%%G"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```